# How do transition scenes?

Tags: lua, storyboard, coronasdk

I'm building a game, and am using storyboard. On enterScene I call my display object lilEnem from another module. I can't remove him from memeory when I change scenes, and I don't know how to insert him into scene.view since it's a separate file.

```
function level1:enterScene()
local level1Group = level1.view
print( "enteredScene" )

local function goHome(event)
    storyboard.removeAll( )
    storyboard.gotoScene( "mainMenu" )
end

local function pauseUi (event)
    local pauseButton = display.newImage("assets/graphics/gameplay/UI/pause/pause.png", display.contentWidth- 25, 25)

    pauseButton:addEventListener( "tap", goHome )

    level1Group:insert( pauseButton )
end

pauseUi()
--Load and play game song when entered scene
--
--
gameAudio.gamePlay()

-- Spawns lilEnems
--
--
local function spawnLilEnem (event)
        -- Checking myData module for lilEnem ID
        --Storing in local id
        --
        --
        local id = myData.lilEnemId

        --lil Enem will spawn in time math.random gives
        --
        --
        --
        local randomSpawnTime = math.random(0,5000)


        --Calls spawnEnem Module
        --
        --
        lilEnem.spawnEnem(id)

        --Adds 1 to id to give each enem unique id
        --
        --
        myData.lilEnemId = myData.lilEnemId + 1

        --timer will call this function at random times
        --
        --
        local spawnEnemTimer = timer.performWithDelay( randomSpawnTime, spawnLilEnem, 1 )

        --When id reachs == number it will stop spawning enems
        --Number is the highest numbered lil Enem ID
        --This statement decides how many lilEnems spawn
        --
        --
        if id == 5 then
            timer.cancel( spawnEnemTimer )
        end
end
spawnLilEnem()

--Call score from scoreData module
--score = 0 in scoreDate module
--
--
local score = display.newText(scoreData.score, display.contentWidth/2, 50, nil, 30)
```

end

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to use Composer as Storyboard will be deprecated.  There is a conversion page...it's not very difficult:

[Storyboard to Composer Migration](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/composer/migration.html)

When you call composer.gotoScene (or Storyboard) you can pass params to that scene:

```
 (main.lua)

 storyboard.gotoScene("MyScene", 
  { 
     params = 
        { 
           param1 = "something", 
           player = playerObj, etc. 
        } 
  }
```

Then, in the called scene, in the "show" method, you can read those params (this code is using the composer):

```
(MyScene.lua)

local scene = composer.newScene()

function scene:show(event)
  if event.phase == "did" then 
     if event.params then
       something = event.params.something
       player = event.params.player 
     end
  end
end

scene:addEventListener("show", scene)

return scene
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove an item when leave scene, use the `exitScene()` method: remove event listeners, stop animations, pause physics, *remove references to display objects* you no longer need, etc.

For inserting into separate view, scenes are like any other Lua module, so you can call a function of the module that does the setting:

```
-- yourGotoScene.lua
local value -- hide it from other modules

function setValue(newValue)
    value = newValue
    print('setting value to new:', value)
end

-- yourCallingScene.lua
...
require 'yourGotoScene'
yourGotoScene.setValue(123)
storyboard.gotoScene('yourGotoScene')
```